# MapKit user location Pin Annotation information

Tags: ios

[image]

i have a map with Annotations and when anyone click on any Annotation its alert with information that i have been programmed it.but the only annotation that is not loaded with my infos is the one that the user current location is near by.how could i solve this problem and make the annotation of the current location appear with infos.

here is the little code of user current location

```
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow;
```

when i click on this alert in pic nothing happen coz its the current location.but others are worked perfectly

Comment: Zoom in as mush as the current Location and near Annotation differentiate...and check what happens>

Comment: Add user location the same way as others annotations. And set [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];

Comment: non of them worked.when i opened my map it goes immediatly to the current location to the nearset annotation and the infos not appear when i click on it

Answer (score 0):

For this you can override user location by

1. On mapview uncheck the 'shows user location'
2. fetch coordinates of User from delegate methods
3. Use those coordinates in custom annotations.

This way your user location can be overridden.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i did all of that before my friend but didn't work.look to the pic when i click on alert nothing happen